# SQL code for last login not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, authentication, ado

I have a login system that uses SQL to create and login users. I also have a update SQL statement on the login page that will show the data that you last logged in on. For some reason my SQL code is not working.

Here is my code:

`UPDATE logins SET lastlogon = NOW() WHERE username = @user`

When I execute this SQL statement it does not update the database for some reason it does not work. I am using Asp.net 4.5. This is also MYSQL code if the will make a difference. I have done a little research and some people have said some stuff about formatting but I have not been able to fix my mysql code. I would like my code to update the database so I can see who logged in at which time. My code does not throw a specific error but it just does not work.

update I now know that it is probably not the SQL code and it is the C# backend.

So here is my code:

```
data connection = new data();
connection.newconnection();
MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE logins SET lastlogon = NOW() WHERE username = '@user'", connection.connect);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString());
update.ExecuteNonQuery();
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username.Text, false);
connection.closeconnection();
update.Dispose();
```

Comment: This code is syntactically correct.  You're going to have to do some debugging to determine why it's "not working".  Does it get executed at all?  What is the  value for `@user`?  What happens when you execute this statement manually with the same value?

Comment: @David I have been able to execute it manually just not in code

Comment: Then something else is wrong.  We can't see your code, so we can't know what.  You're going to have to debug this to find the problem.

Comment: try using SQL Profiler to catch what is actually sent to the database (edit: just noticed it's mysql tagged - oh well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I just figured it out. For some reason I put the login redirect below the line of code that updates the sql database so it does not have a user to update.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the `'` around `@user`. The parameterized query will fill that in.

```
UPDATE logins SET lastlogon = NOW() WHERE username = @user
```

Comment: I just tried that and it did not help anything

Comment: @AidenGrossman please post any exceptions that you receive or may be swallowing.

Comment: The application did not throw any exceptions it just did not work

Comment: @AidenGrossman This answer is definitely part of your problem, also use your debugger and check that whatever value `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` has is in your database's `logins` table.